# Modal with variable content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native.

My screen contains 5 buttons, each one opens the same `<Modal>`, but the `<View>` inside it will change depending on the button clicked.

If I click the first button, a text input will be shown into the modal.

If I click the second button, a switch will be shown into the modal.

I've made a modal component (Modal.tsx) :

```
export default class Modal extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <View style={style.modal} >
        {this.props.children}
      <View>
    )
  };
}

// Specific modal implementation with TextInput
const ModalWithTextInput = props => (
  <Modal>
    <TextInput
      value={props.someValue}
    />
  <Modal>
)


// Specific modal implementation with Switch
const ModalWithSwitch = props => (
  <Modal>
    <Switch
      value={props.someValue}
    />
  <Modal>
)
```

And now in my 5-button-screen (ButtonsScreen.tsx), I need to open the right modal depending on the button clicked :

```
openTextModal = () => {
   this.setState({ modalType: 'text' });
}

openSwitchModal = () => {
   this.setState({ modalType: 'switch' });
}
```

These functions are called with `onPress={this.openTextModal}`

Finally, I need to render the modal, to be able to do something like :

```
<View>
   {this.renderModal(modalType)}
</View>
```

**But I don't know how to deal with the renderModal function**

```
renderModal = (type) => {
    if (type === 'text') {
        return ???
    }

    if (type === 'switch') {
        return ???
    }
}
```

Anyone can please help ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use all you've already done to do this :

```
renderModal = (type) => {
    if (type === 'text') {
        return <ModalWithTextInput someValue="default text" />
    }

    if (type === 'switch') {
        return <ModalWithSwitch someValue={false} />
    }
}
```

Be sure to import these components in your file to be able to use them (not needed if you declared them in the same file)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried that but the modal isn't opening. Any ideas why ?

Comment: Do you have any error or warning ? If the modal component is the one you wrote yourself, try changing his style.

Comment: No error, no warning... is the function openTextModal really opening the modal ?

Answer (score 0):

All you want to do is change the content the Modal renders. So you do not need to render different Modals for them just the content. Do not forget to set the modal state to `visible`.

```
renderModal = () => (
  <View>
    <Modal visible={this.state.modalVisible}>
     {this.renderModalContent()}
    </Modal>
  </View>)

renderModalContent = () => {
  if(this.state.modalType === 'switch'){
    return (<Switch
      value={props.someValue}
    />);
  } else {
   return (
    <TextInput
      value={props.someValue}
    />)
  }
}
```